Anycubic: change default temperature for filament in/out command?
The last thread I found on this is a couple years old now -- https://www.reddit.com/r/AnycubicVyper/comments/vv8wwl/filament_change_temp_question/
Does anyone know of an update or an alternate firmware load that allows changing the temperature?

With thanks to  "susmaster208"     on a reddit thread, those brave enough can install this 3rd-party firmware :  MB-CE_6.2
